# Helm delete release and clear associated storage

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I install the helm release by

```
helm install --name my-release .
```

And delete it by

```
helm delete --purge my-release
```

But I found out that kubernetes does not clear any storage associated to the containers of that release. I installed postgresql, did lot of things to it, deleted, and when I reinstalled it, all my data was there. How do I clear the storage via helm delete?

**Edit:** I'm using [Postgresql Stable Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql) version `5.3.10`

Here's the only custom thing I have in my release

values.yaml

```
postgresql:
  postgresqlDatabase: test
  postgresqlUsername: test
  postgresqlPassword: test
```

Comment: Are you using any persistent volume for PostgreSQL?

Comment: I didn't set any, although it does use some default as I see. But I wonder if there's any way to delete it using helm, and not doing a brute `rm -rf` on the cluster

Comment: Can you add the helm chart file in the question which sets the volume?

Comment: I don't customize it at all, I just added a postgresql dependency, set username password, and installed the release

Comment: Are you using the postgresql helm chart from stable repo https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql ?

Comment: Yes, just edited the question

Comment: Where are you installing the chart? I mean how your kubernetes cluster is built? Is it an on-premise cluster or from a cloud provider?

Comment: I trier both on minikube and DigitalOcean cluster, both gave me the same result

Comment: Can you add the results of `kubectl get pv`, `kubectl get pvc`,  and `kubectl get sc` to the question? Also add the location  of the data that is persisted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the helm chart file:
https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/postgresql/templates/statefulset.yaml

It is evident that if you don't specify the value for `.Values.persistence.existingClaim` in values.yaml, it will automatically create a persistent volume claim.

- If you have a storage calss set for `.Values.persistence.storageClass` the created pvc will use that class to provision volumes.
- If you set the storage class as "-", the dynamic provisioning will be disabled.
- If you don't specify anything for `.Values.persistence.storageClass`, the automatically created pvc will not have a storage class field specified.

Since you are using the default values.yaml of the chart, you have the third case.

In kubernetes, if you don't specify a storage class in a persistent volume claim, it will use the **default storage class** of the cluster to provision volumes.

Check which is your cluster's stoage class:

```
kubectl get sc
```

The default StorageClass will be marked by `(default)`. 
Describe that storage class and find it's `Reclaim Policy`.

If the Reclaim Policy is **Delete**, the pv created by it will be automatically deleted when it's claim is removed (In your case, when the chart is uninstalled).

If the default storage class's Reclaim Policy is not  **Delete**, you have to create your own storage class with Delete policy and then use it further.

Comment: So I need to make sure to look through the chart description carefully. Didn't know about the default values. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at default value in default `values.yaml` [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/postgresql/values.yaml):

```
persistence:
  enabled: true
```

By setting it to **false** we can disable the persistence so that after uninstalling the helm release, the data is not persisted.

To achieve this, create your own values file with following contents:

```
persistence:
  enabled: false

#Sample command
helm install myrelease --values values-override.yaml bitnami/postgresql
```